# Wrap content in a div using selectors

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Don't know how to phrase it any better. Can I use CSS selectors to inject an extra wrapper `<div>` around the content of target `<div>`?

So let's say my page looks like this:

```
<div>
  <h3>Something</h3>
  <img src='/../../img/logo.jpg' />
</div>
```

I want to change it through css to:

```
<div>
  <div id='newlyAddedDiv' class='something'>
    <h3>Something</h3>
    <img src='/../../img/logo.jpg' />
  </div>
</div>
```

Is this possible through css selectors or psuedo-selectors? I looked into `before`, `after`, `first-child` etc., but they don't seem to do the trick.

### Edit

Here is the problem. I am working with a grid (somewhat like a photo gallery) and want to add margin around each item. This is Bootstrap 4 BTW.

```
<div id='Gallery'>
  <div class='col-3'>
    <h3>
    <img>
    <p>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

This creates a 4-columns grid. Adding margin on the parent div (col-3) affects the grid itself (I understand why this happens). I can't add margin/padding to the content elements either (because their are multiple). So I thought it would be easy if I could inject a "wrapper" `div` around the content and add margin to it. Unfortunately this too doesn't seem to be a possibility now.

Comment: no, you cannot. CSS is for CSS not to change the HTML. JS is made for that

Comment: @TemaniAfif: Oh well. Just realized what this could do. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: btw, if you describe your requirement instead of describing the solution you think is right we may probably help you finding a CSS solution to achieve what you want

Comment: Yes, it is true that CSS is not for changing the actual DOM structure itself. However it depends what you want to achieve. Could you expand on what you want to do with the new div?

Comment: @TemaniAfif: Sure. Just edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to transform this:

```
<div id='Gallery'>
  <div class='col-3'>
    <h3>
    <img>
    <p>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

Into this:

```
<div id='Gallery'>
  <div class='col-3'>
    <div class="new">
      <h3>
      <img>
      <p>
    </div>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

To be able to add margin to `.new`. In this case you can simply add the margin to the content inside like below:

```
.col-3 > * {
   margin:0 10px 0; /*no magin-top/bottom*/
}

.col-3 > :first-child {
   margin:10px 10px 0; /*no margin-bottom*/
}
.col-3 > :last-child {
   margin:0 10px 10px; /*no margin-top*/
}
```

Sample code:

```css
img {
  width:80px;
}
.col-3 {
  outline:1px solid red;
}
.col-3 > * {
   margin:0 10px 0; /*no magin-top/bottom*/
}

.col-3 > :first-child {
   margin:10px 10px 0; /*no margin-bottom*/
}
.col-3 > :last-child {
   margin:0 10px 10px; /*no margin-top*/
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
<div id='Gallery' class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class='col-3'>
      <h3>Title</h3>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=0">
    </div>
    <div class='col-3'>
      <h3>Title</h3>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=0">
      <p>lorem</p>
    </div>
    <div class='col-3'>
      <h3> title</h3>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=0">
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class='col-3'>
      <h3>title</h3>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=0">
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class='col-3'>
      <h3>title<br>long</h3>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=0">
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This seemingly did the trick, when I replaced `margin` with `padding`. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

CSS only changes style of the page. It **can't** change DOM (Document Object Model). You can use JS or some server-side code for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with `CSS`, but you can do it with `JavaScript`

> Example

```js
// find elements
var banner = $("#banner-message > img")
var button = $("button")

// handle click and add class
button.on("click", function(){
  $(banner).wrap('<div class="new-parent"></div>');
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/CtZQRga.jpg" width="100" height="100" />
  <button>Change color</button>
</div>
```